# Is there a hadran text recited upon completing the Rambam's Mishneh Torah?

Tags: rambam, siyum, mishneh-torah

Is there a set text for a siyum upon completion of the Mishneh Torah?  Perhaps something like the Hadran said upon completion of a masechet of Talmud.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific format. Chabad completes it yearly and makes a siyum that usually involves finishing the last cycle, starting the new one, and saying an apropos dvar torah.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You can write one

Comment: My Rosh Yeshiva, a"h, said that upon finishing Mishneh Torah, one can say *hadran alach kol hatorah kuloh*, so I assume he just meant the standard text with *kol hatorah kulah* (the entire Torah) as the subject of study. He pointed out that you can't say that on finishing the entire Talmud, because, as opposed to the Mishneh Torah, the Talmud doesn't cover all aspects of Jewish law.